# How can I reinstall Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I want to reinstall ubuntu but when I insert a live cd into my pc there is no option for reinstalling.

It shows options to either `Install Ubuntu alongside Ubuntu` and `Remove the data from the pc and then install Ubuntu`.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a bug.

Reinstalling = Remove all data and install over it. What were you expecting? Did you want to keep your data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16010/discussion-between-tim-and-agha-rehan-abbas).